# What are these strange red and blue squares?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

At floor 7 of Dungeons of Dredmor I found these strange red and blue squares. How can I interacet with them and what should I expect?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I seem to remember getting a mana (blue square) or health (red square) buff after walking over them.  I don't remember that clearly though, so commenting instead of answering :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The blue square acts as a potion of purity/Zodiac wand: it will remove buffs and debuffs. (I think it only removes 1 hit from buffs that are related to being hit/hitting X times)
The red square will debuff you (lower sight radius) and summon 4 monsters.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it gives you a buff (I can't remember exactly what the buff did), but most of the time, in my experience, it gives you a debuff which decreases sight range, as well as spawning four monsters around you.